# how to get list of all streets in poland from Google maps api

Tags: maps, street-address

I need to get list of all streets in Poland with their cities and and zip codes. Should I write a small program that collects all the streets in Poland?

Answer (score 0):

No. It violates their [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) in the clauses of "No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content" and also "No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content."